# Is there a name for the fallacy that one vote has no effect on the outcome?

Tags: word-choice

I often hear this in elections where people justify not going to vote, because (according to them) *"their vote doesn't change anything"* or the like.

This kind of reasoning is also used to discard vegetarianism, because *"if I eat meat or not - that cow is gonna get killed"*.

Although it seems to be true at first, the decision does have an effect in the end due to accumulation and the butterfly effect. (If everybody would reason that way, there would be nobody doing it.)

Comment: First, it's worth pointing out that this isn't a fallacy (neither in logic nor rhetoric). The decision to not vote, or eat meat, or whatever, can be made on a rational, individual, basis, without regard for the decisions of other agents. That said, I'll think about a common word or term for "small things add up".

Comment: *Whatever you do in life will be insignificant, but it is very important that you do it ...* [Gandhi](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/907005-whatever-you-do-in-life-will-be-insignificant-but-it)

Comment: The only vote that matters is the one that breaks the tie.

Comment: @DanBron Well, I would say it is a fallacy, because it's an argument that uses poor reasoning. These people disregard the proven "butterfly effect", that "small things add up" and that decisions can be made without regard for the decisions of other agents.

Comment: Check out the main/perfect solution fallacy (aka the nirvana fallacy) -- it doesn't directly apply to this scenario but it's definitely related. "There's no way to make a perfect solution, so I'm just not going to bother putting forth an effort at all": http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PerfectSolutionFallacy

Comment: This is related to the *sorites* paradox, which is that one grain of sand is not a heap, and there doesn't seem to be any identifiable point where adding a single grain of sand changes a "not heap" into a "heap" and yet somehow you can still construct a heap of sand one grain at a time.  I don't agree with @DanBron's evaluation that this is not a fallacy of a sort, but I'm not aware of a specific name for it.  You might take this question to http://philosophy.stackexchange.com if you are more interested in the implications than the terminology.

Comment: @Joschua, the decision is rational in the moment; that makes it a rational decision. Individuals are under no obligation to take into account the broader needs of the group when making rational decisions.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Good point! Actually I'm interested in both the philosophical implications and the terminology. :)

Comment: @DanBron Please explain how it is a rational decision to, for example, not vote! Saying something is a "rational decision" is not a valid argument.

I agree that "individuals are under no obligation to take into account the broader needs of the group when making rational decisions" (although sometimes it makes sense to do so), but making the decision not to vote isn't only about the needs of the group, it's also about your own needs, as it can have a negative effect on yourself as well.

Comment: @Joschua, there is endless literature on this subject, and I don't have space to reprise it in a comment. Google "paradox of voting" (or, if you really want to get into the weeds, "Arrow's impossibility theorem", which proves no possible voting system can have all the desired characteristics, and in particular current voting systems admit what is known as "strategic voting", and *one of the strategies employed is abstention*). More specifically, not-voting may be the most Pareto efficient choice (satisficing), as the benefit of voting may be outweighed by the cost (inconvenience, for example).

Comment: @DanBron Just because no voting system can be perfect or one finds voting inconvenient, that doesn't imply that not voting is a rational decision. That's the [PerfectSolutionFallacy](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PerfectSolutionFallacy) again and even if the effort of voting outweighs (which is completely subjective) the benefits for you, it still adds up overall. Anyway, thanks for the discussion! :)

Comment: @Joschua, no, sorry. Read the links I pointed you at, particularly the paradox of voting and Pareto efficiency. You may not like it, you may not agree, you may wish to win an argument elsewhere, but non-voting can and is perfectly rational (sorry I confused you with the technical details of Arrow's paradox; that's probably overkill for the sake of the current discussion, but note it has nothing to do with needing a "perfect system" to justify or not non-voting, and everything to do with the theoretical and practical motivation behind strategic, rational, [non-] voting).

Comment: Assuming all candidates meet the criteria for a position, it shouldn't matter who wins. (If it does, fix the criteria). Pulling a name from a hat fixes practically all voting issues, including the issue of voting for/against everyone else.

Comment: @DanBron Well, you misunderstood me. I didn't say nor imply that I won the argument. The "thanks for the discussion" was meant earnestly, as I think it's interesting to see different points of view and I said it, because the discussion seemed to be at a dead end (because you didn't respond to my criticism). I also looked at, addressed and disagreed with the "paradox of voting". Regarding pareto efficiency: I'd like to know how you know that you're [not-]voting will "make at least one individual better off without making any other individual worse off".

Comment: @Joschua, no, you misunderstood me. I wasn't discussing our back-and-forth about the topic, I said "*You may wish to win an argument **elsewhere***", meaning I speculated that the original motivation for asking this question was a dispute with someone else (a non-voter, a non-vegetarian, whatever).  And as I said earlier, you can "dispute" the paradox of voting, but that doesn't make it go away. There is volumes of literature on this topic --literally decades-- and all of it disagrees with your position that this is a "fallacy". In re: Pareto, you need to Google that in the context of voting.

Comment: @DanBron Well, this wasn't my intention at all. But you seem to feel pretty offended (and apologetic). As I already said, you didn't address my criticism and telling me that there is volumes of literature is NOT an argument. There is also volumes of literature about ghosts and zombies (that arise on Easter).. Does this imply they exist? No!

Comment: @Joschua, no, no I'm not offended, and no I'm not apologetic (no idea how you came to that thought). And I did say there was volumes of literature that *you should Google* because there isn't space or time to address it in a comment (nor is it appropriate to do so, because it's only tangentially related to your question, in that your question is poorly worded, or poorly conceived, depending).  You probably will not be surprised to learn that the literature on voting theory is qualitatively different from the "literature" on ghosts, but you could find out first hand **if you did the research**.

Comment: @DanBron What about these [responses to the paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_voting#Responses)? I assume they are all completely wrong too, right?

Comment: @Joschua, I think you may be missing something very fundamental here: the very existence of the paradox as something for people to discuss invalidates your position that non-voting can't be a rational decision, and that the defense of that decision is a fallacy. Your position is invalid. There is nothing else to say about it; you are not disagreeing with me, you are disagreeing with 5 decades of economists and political philosophers. (Though I am glad to see you've actually begun to independently investigate the topic, which may lead you to eventually understand *why* your position is invalid)

Comment: @DanBron Truth isn't about quantity (or decades). Maybe you misunderstood them. Have you any book recommendations about this topic? | How does the existence of this paradox invalidate my position, that every vote has an impact? And if every vote has an impact, it isn't rational to not vote, because you could change things for the better. (Given there are different choices, you have an opinion about them, you actually want to vote and are not too lazy to do it.) There's always the possibility of exercising the pivotal vote and even if one doesn't, it may lead to somebody else making it!

Comment: @Joschua, please note that every time you post comment which mentions me, I get a notification (through several channels), even if you later retract your comment (meaning, please make sure you have all your thoughts together before commenting, because I'm getting a lot noise). In re your repetition of your original argument without having taken into account any new information I provided you: surprisingly, that does not change my responses. And I am not asserting decades make something true, I'm telling you you are wrong, and there is decades worth of material which will explain to you **why**

Comment: @DanBron Well mistakes happen and sometimes commends get posted that are not ready. | Why should I take your information into account IF it doesn't make any sense. You are the one who didn't respond to a single of my questions and criticism. That's it. Bye! :P

Comment: @Joschua First, for this very reason (courtesy to other users) you should edit, not delete, mistaken comments.  If you don't think the 5 minutes will be enough time to compose your final thoughts, you should polish them up outside the site and post them when they're finished. In re: not responding to your questions, I think you've misunderstood;  I **have**. I'm telling you there's a *sea* of material out there that **would**, if you just read it, make sense to you, and settle your doubts. In other words: Nobel laureates have explained it much better and deeper than I ever could in a comment.

Comment: I do agree with @DanBron: a fallacy is a fault in logic or rhetoric, which implies poor reasoning. If I say "Whether I eat meat or not, the cow is going to die anyway", that's a perfectly sound argument, and the cow will die indeed. The actual faulty reasoning would be "No matter how many people choose to eat meat or not, that cow is going to get killed", because if the whole world population stopped eating meat, that would actually make a difference. But your sentence is taking into account the decision of a **single** agent, whose actions alone are largely irrelevant to the food industry.

Comment: @vi3x *"Whether I eat meat or not, the cow is going to die anyway"* is not a perfectly sound argument, because it **could** be that this *one* decision, to not eat meat, makes the tipping point (supply and demand), so that this cow **does not** get killed. I didn't say "that cow **will likely** die". (If that was the case, I would agree.) So, the decision of a single agent isn't irrelevant, because it accumulates and, as **[chaos theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory)** has proved, *small differences in initial conditions yield entirely different outcomes*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a type of **self-fulfilling prophecy.**  The failure to act because the odds of success are very slim only ensures or helps to ensure the bad outcome.

This is slightly different from the literary theme that portrays *heros* as individuals who act even though the odds of success are absolutely zero, such as the protagonist of Albert Camus' *The Plague.*

Comment: I gotta ask: Who is Gary, and why are you his student? :-)

Comment: @Cyberherbalist  He was a person who helped me a lot when I was  young.  My username is a reminder to myself to try to help others as much as he helped me.